# I need to make a gap between my header and image div disappear?

Tags: html, header, space, nav

Here is the relevant html (with the image at the top of my page and then the header containing my nav:

```
</head>
   <div id="something"><img src="Images/guysonlycopy.jpg" alt="image" width="1200" height="300" /></div>  
       <header>  
           <style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>     
 <div id="wrapper">
<ul id="nav">
<li class="current"><a href="http://www.webdesignerwall.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com">Sports</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">NFL========></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.nfl.com/teams">Teams</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nfl.com/standings">Tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nfl.com/news">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nfl.com/fantasyfootball">Fantasy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discuss</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">NBA========></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.nba.com/teams/">Teams</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html">Standings</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nba.com/news/">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nba.com/fantasy/">Fantasy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discuss</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Football=====></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html">BPL</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html">BPL Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables">Tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://fantasy.premierleague.com/">Fantasy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cricket======></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.ecb.co.uk/">England</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket/county-championship-division-one/table">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/cricket/">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cricket20.com/">T20</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Games</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Populars====></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">game1</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game2</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game3</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game4</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game5</a></il>
            </ul>
            </il>
        <li><a href="#">Recent=====></a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">game1</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game2</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game3</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game4</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game5</a></il>
            </ul>
            </il>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        </ul>

</li>

<li><a href="#">Cool Shit</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Populars====></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">thing1</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">thing2</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">thing3</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">thing4</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">thing5</a></il>
            </ul>
            </il>
        <li><a href="#">Recent=====></a>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">game1</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game2</a></il>
                <li><a href="#">game3</a></il>
            </ul>
            </il>
        <li><a href="#">The Rest</a></li>
        </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>


       </ul><!-- End Nav -->
   </header><!-- End Header -->
```

And this is the css which effects the nav and above:

```
/* Body
--------------------------------------------*/




body {
font: normal .8em/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #ebebeb;
    width: 1200px;
margin: 100px auto;
color: #666;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: #ccc;
margin: 0;
width: 1200px;
display: block;
padding: 0;
}




/* Header
--------------------------------------------*/

header {
background-color: #170a6e;
height: 100px;
width: 1200px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

header h1 {
font-size: 4.5em;
float: left;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;

}

#something {
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: block;
}

#title {
float: left;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-top: 11px;
}


/* Nav
--------------------------------------------*/


#nav {

margin: 0;
padding: 7px 6px 0;
line-height: 100%;

-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 2em;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0;

-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2em;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0; 

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
alignment-adjust: central;

background: #0e0575; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a9a9a9',    endColorstr='#7a7a7a'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#a9a9a9), to(#7a7a7a)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a9a9a9,  #7a7a7a); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

border: solid 1px #6d6d6d;

display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
#nav li {
margin: 0 6px;
padding: 0 0 8px;
float: left;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
}
/* main level link */
#nav a {
font-weight: bold;
color: #e7e5e5;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding:  8px 20px;
margin: 0;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1.6em;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 1.6em;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1.6em;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 1.6em;

-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1.6em;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 1.6em;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1.6em;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1.6em;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
/* main level link hover */
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
background: #d1d1d1; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ebebeb', endColorstr='#a1a1a1'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ebebeb), to(#a1a1a1)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ebebeb,  #a1a1a1); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

color: #030375;
border-top: solid 1px #f8f8f8;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
/* sub levels link hover */
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
background: none;
border: none;
color: #1f049f;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
background: #0399d4 !important; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#04acec', endColorstr='#0186ba'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba)) !important; /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #04acec,  #0186ba) !important; /* for firefox 3.6+ */

color: #fff !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
background: #ddd; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cfcfcf'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#cfcfcf));        /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #cfcfcf); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

display: none;
margin: 0 5px;
padding: 0;
width: 185px;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 0;
border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;

-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
#nav ul li {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 3px;
}
#nav ul a {
font-weight: normal;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}
/* level 3+ list */
#nav ul ul {
left: 181px;
top: -7px;
}
/* rounded corners for first and last child */
#nav ul li:first-child > a {
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 9px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 9px;
}
#nav ul li:last-child > a {
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 9px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 9px;
}
/* clearfix */
#nav:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

html[xmlns] #nav {
display: block;
}
* html #nav {
height: 1%;
}
```

Just to be clear I want to get rid of the gap between my image div and header.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if scottie's answer did not fix it, can you could put the code in jsfiddle? i had a quick go, and once the html is sorted it seems ok, but without seeing the actual problem it's hard to know

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is messed up... you've got a div and an opening header tag before the opening body tag. Dunno if that's your problem or not, but a correct DOM tree is probably a good place to start troubleshooting.